# Testing REQUIRES_NEW in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

When running my test, it hangs at the call to method(). Am I doing something wrong? Help!

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"beans.xml"})
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        itemUnderTestDao.method();
        // ...
    }
}

public class ItemUnderTestDao {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void method() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Forget the above code. I have now uploaded an Eclipse project (excluding dependencies like spring) at http://www44.zippyshare.com/v/46865082/file.html. All input on how to get the test to pass is really appreciated! The test pass if I have two sqlite databases and two dataSources...

Comment: Do you execute any other code that accesses the database in your test?

Comment: Hi @aandeers, I know its pretty old post, but do you remember how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mrembisz said you are trying to get 2 connections at the same time/thread.

1. For test itself, which would exist for a duration of the test
2. For a method call, which would exist for duration of the call.

I encountered the same thing in a little bit different circumstances.

2 ways you can fix this:

1. Change propagation to `REQUIRED`, this way you would reuse Connection that test originally acquired.
2. Increase pool size, but keep in mind, that you need to consider max number of simultanious updates, roughly **`maxThreadPoolSize >= (maxSimultaniousUpdates + 1) + (min size for other activities)`** (If you have at list 1 pending connection, eventually all pending operations would complete). Othrewise this would reappear in production.

First solution seems to me better one, ofcourse if it does not harm your logic :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open second connection to the database. The first one is opened because of `@Transactional` for class `Test`, `REQUIRES_NEW` on `method()` forces another connection.

Probably your connection pool allows only one concurrent connection. Check its size and database configuration.

Also run through your questions and mark selected answers as accepted (a checkmark shape next to the answer body).

Comment: `<bean id="dataSourcePool" ...>
    ...
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="200"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>`

Comment: @AndersOlofsson Change max size to 2 or more in `<property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>`.

Comment: @AndersOlofsson I suspect an old copy of your xml is still being used. Try to enable higher logging for your pool classes, you should see the actual values.

Comment: I have enabled higher logging and can see that the maxPoolSize is 2.

Comment: @AndersOlofsson Your database could be limited to one connection then. You can run your test under debugger and abort hanging thread to see the actual stack trace - this will give you a clue about the nature of encountered lock.